# Norms on tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $A$ be an algebra of operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $A^m$ and $A^n$ be free $A$-modules with bases $e_1, \ldots, e_m$ and $f_1, \ldots, f_n$. Define a norm on $A^m \otimes A^n$ as follows:
$$\left| \sum a_i e_i \otimes b_j f_j \right| = \sup_{X_i, Y_j} \left|\sum a_i X_i b_j Y_j\right|.$$
The sup is taken over all collections of operators $X_i$, $Y_j$ on $H$ of norm no more than 1. The norm on the right is the operator norm.
Has anyone considered these? Is there any chance that the norms defined for $A^m \otimes A^n$ and for $A^n \otimes A^m$ be compared?

Comment: to get some comparison inequalities, you might benefit from searching for Pisier's survey on Grothendieck inequalities...

Comment: Should't it be $\sum_{i,j,k} a_{k,i}e_i\otimes b_{k,j}f_j$, since it's a tensor product?

Comment: Exactly, sorry, I suppressed the index k.